# SQL Openquery - Object has no columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mdx, linked-server

I have a dynamically Stored Procedure, which creates an mdx statement for an OpenQuery. So it can happen that the objects from the mdx statement are empty. In this case I want back an empty string.

Generally, the query works except when I choose a date that is from the future in which case the SQL Server gives me this error:

> "The OLE DB provider "XYZ" for linked server "XYZ" indicates that
>   either the object has no columns or the current user does not have
>   permissions on that object."

```
    select
        t.*
            from OPENQUERY([SomeServer_OLAP],''
            SELECT
                non empty{[Measures].[FactWorkItemHistory Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate],
                [Measures].[FactWorkItemHistory Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork],
                [Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork]} ON COLUMNS
                , NON EMPTY { ([Work Item].[Iteration Path].[Iteration Path].ALLMEMBERS 
                * [Work Item].[System_AssignedTo].[System_AssignedTo].ALLMEMBERS)} on ROWS
                FROM [Team System]
                WHERE '+@Month+'  
                                '') t'
```

So, entering the date parameter for December (the month of writing this post) works fine, but entering January of 2018 (next month) and all the other following months returns the error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing "non empty" from the query fixed my issue. There doesn't seems to be any immediate observable drawbacks to this.

Comment: For some non future dates you might end up with blank rows or columns if you remove either of the NonEmpties